# How do we get JSON response from action

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I am quite new to Java EE. I am facing an issue.

Here I have requirement for Test.jsp which should have following function

1) Jsp will have one input area where json String input request can be placed.

2) drop down list which shows following list

```
https://localhost:9443/my.do

https://localhost:9443/my2.do
```

3) submit button : on submit Javascript take the input json request send it to corrosponding action selected in  dropdown.

4) Output area: which shows Json response from action.

You can keep any tool to parse json like Jquery in jsp

> Object     {  “result code”       : “OK”  “resultMessage” : “ ” }

please Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the response's content type to "application/json" and write JSON encoded objects to the response stream.

Comment: Can you please give me example code that I can understand clearly As I am Quite new.
Thanks.